# opengl - Ubuntu: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 90

Tags: c, ubuntu, compilation

I have been looking around unfortunately most of the proposed solutions are for PHP or something like that. I have some C-code in openGL on my laptop which is running Ubuntu.

However when I try to compile some code which uses the "jpeglib" library, I get this error:

```
Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 90
```

How can I solve this issue?

When I try: sudo apt-get install libjpeg8, it claims the newest version is already install. But it looks like I'd need libjpeg9 (according to the error message)

EDIT: I am running ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: What is your version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: This is not a programming issue, but about general system versioning.